# Failed to load component from module error After using webpack

Tags: nativescript

So my app was working fine until I updated the framework and enabled webpack, 
the issue is when I load a modal view it gives the following error:

```
System.err: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onItemClick failed
System.err:
System.err: Error: Failed to load component from module: ./rest-page-model.xml or file: null
```

At first I had the same issue with loading pages, The underscore in the page name was causing the issue, so I changed the name and removed the underscore from the page name then it worked, but this trick did not work with the modal view

```
function ToResturantList(args) {
    const button = args.object;

    const typeOfResturants=button.id;
    const featuredFrame = frameModule.getFrameById("main");
    featuredFrame.navigate({

        moduleName: "Resturants-list-page", 



        transition: 
            {
                name:"slideBottom"
            } ,

            context:{typeOfResturants:typeOfResturants}


    });
}exports.ToResturantList=ToResturantList;
```

Comment: Your `Resturants-list-page` is placed under app directory?

Comment: Yes, everything was working fine only when I enabled webpack

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the main difference between the legacy workflow and the bundle one is the way we register and load the pages and custom components. The above-mentioned error says that your login page is not included in the app bundle.

I strongly recommend you read the blog post describing this workflow switch. It describes how were we copying the whole app folder when using the legacy workflow compared to copying only the required files when using the bundle workflow (reducing the app size). The important part for this issue is that in order to include all of the required app pages and custom components, the bundle workflow is using a few conventions described in this thread.

In short, the bundle workflow is including only the pages ending with page and root and in order to get your app working, you need to rename this login.xml, login.ts and login.css files to login-page.xml, login-page.ts and login-page.css. Bear in mind that you have to do this for all of your pages and also fix the page navigations.

Please, update us back if you still have any errors after you follow the page conventions or manually register your pages as described in the above-related thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I deleted the page and created new one, everything is working fine now